# c# wpf memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I've recently made a desktop application that communicates with a device at my job.

The general idea of the app is to give the device (oven) a "set temperature" command and after every 10 seconds check the current temperature and display it on a graph using livecharts.

This application is required to run multiple days at a time and I seem to be having a memory leak problem, I think.
What I experience is the application not responding for a while, then it becomes responsive and adds 1 single "log" effect as in LogTemp function every around 1-2 minutes. It should be once every 10 seconds.

Edit: Just read the lines before this edit and I think I was not too clear. It works as it is supposed to work the first few hours. Noticed the performance took a hit only after 24 hours.

After 24 hours of running I came back to find it is using over 800 MB of RAM and it kept growing by the second.

I suspect it MAY have something to do with [livecharts](https://lvcharts.net) but I am not sure by any means. (it ends up with 8640 points of data after 24 hours)

I have no issue disclosing my code and have even minimized the amount of code needed to be shown to around 200 lines in total which are split to a few different functions, but if anyone heard of such an issue with livecharts and/or can suggest a different type of graph library I'd be more than happy to swap it out.

`Actually, here's the code, lmao:`

https://pastebin.com/YBn5CuD6

Another thing I thought of, could it be that I am adding too many rows to the ListView? We're talking about.. 8640 rows in 24 hours. Might that be something to do with it?

Sorry for the long post, thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running this for a long period of time under a Visual Studio diagnostic session, tracking memory usage?  The report you get from that would probably be helpful in determining the source of the leak.  Just go to *Debug >> Performance Profiler*.

Comment: The issue only appears after quite a few hours (I don't know for sure, but I doubt anything less than 10-15 hours) and I have no collections/bindings that are being updated during this constant loop. The code posted (excluding the 2 functions I mentioned and did not post SetTemp and GetTemp) is the only piece of code running (on a separate thread) until the cycles are finished. And I found the issue before the cycles finished. The GUI itself is only being updated in the displayed code with the ListView and LiveCharts chart.

Comment: @Joe I will definitely run this and come back with more information. Thank you.

Comment: What does this do?  "Database.AddTemperature" I would assume you are not keeping DB connections open etc. and are correctly disposing Tables, Command etc. in your Db code.

Comment: Off topic- Not related to your memory leak but why not use a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=net-5.0) instead of while loops and thread sleeps. This would simplify the code a lot.

Comment: @bic https://pastebin.com/2pJp4AA7 here is the code for it. I open and close connection every time I have to access the database. Which is an SQLite database. But I am not sure what you mean by disposing tables and command, I may be doing something incorrect, in which case I'd love to be corrected.

Comment: @bic I'll definitely take a look at DispatcherTimer, wasn't aware of it. Thank you for pointing it out, seems like a much better option.

Comment: Ok, looking at your Db code you should start using the [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement. It might be sometihng as simple as not freeing up resources such as command etc. This is what I meant with "disposing". The using statement will dispose objects automatically for you.

Comment: @bic does it not dispose automatically anyways whenever it steps out of scope from the method? I will implement this change however.

Comment: @BartBB: You can't be guaranteed to have unmanaged resources disposed after they leave the scope they are creating in, therefore it's important to always clean up disposable resources. Db resources are a particularly common candidate.

Comment: @bic: Understood. Thanks for the tips, my friend. Truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, I lowered the sample rate which is responsible for how many points are on the LiveCharts chart and it goes very smooth right now, even after 3 days of running.
(RAM usage was also around 90 MB, which is to be expected from my application)

I believe that was the issue, so I'll mark this as an answer for the next person googling LiveCharts memory-leak.